# Running ADB command in terminal disconnect device connected wirelessly

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

The given device is connected via wireless debugging from developer options.

Running the ADB command in the terminal disconnect the wireless connection Android Studio

Example

```
 PS D:\project\exmaple-app> adb shell dumpsys activity
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
error: no devices/emulators found
```

Is my ADB is different? > Not sure but it's the same.
What is causing this and how to fix this?

Comment: You have two incompatible adb versions installed on your system. Search your system for `adb.exe` and retain only the one from Android SDK. Note that you need to reconfigure third party tools that contained their own adb version to use the correct adb.exe afterwards.

Comment: Thank you @Robert, you are right. I use the command `where adb` and found two adb `C:\Windows\adb.exe` `D:\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe` replace it with latest one and then it works!